# How can I split correctly in C?

Tags: c, arrays, split

I want to split an array which includes information from a text file. Firstly, I split and then I insert a node. I write something but still there are mistakes. Can you help me, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person
{
  char *lesson;
  char *name;
  struct person *next;
};

char *
strtok_r (char *str, const char *delim, char **save)
{
  char *res, *last;

  if (!save)
    return strtok (str, delim);
  if (!str && !(str = *save))
    return NULL;
  last = str + strlen (str);
  if ((*save = res = strtok (str, delim)))
    {
      *save += strlen (res);
      if (*save < last)
        (*save)++;
      else
        *save = NULL;
    }
  return res;
}


int
main ()
{

  FILE *fp;
  char names[100][100];
  fp = fopen ("C:\\lesson.txt", "r");

  int i = 0, j = 0;
  while (!feof (fp))
    {
      //fscanf(fp,"%s",names[i]);
      fgets (names[i], sizeof (names), fp);
      i++;
    }
  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
      char *key_value;
      char *key_value_s;

      key_value = strtok_r (names[j], ":", &key_value_s);

      while (key_value)
        {
          char *key, *value, *s;

          key = strtok_r (key_value, ":", &s);
          value = strtok_r (NULL, ",", &s);

          key_value = strtok_r (NULL, ",", &key_value_s);
          insertion (key_value);
        }
    }
}
```

and there is my lesson.txt file:

```
George Adam            :Math,Science,Germany
Elizabeth McCurry      :Music,Math,History
Tom Hans               :Science,Music
```

I want to split names and lessons and I want to insert lessons. But I just can only insert names. I use strtok_r but I think it doesn't work correctly. Because I'm sure that my insertion function is correct. I waant to help for splitting tokens.

My output like this:

```
Elizabeth McCurry, George Adam, Tom Hans
```

But I want to an output like this:

```
Germany, History, Math, Music, Science
```

Comment: Okey I delete @BhargavRao

Comment: Why do you use capslock. I just only ask a question for help somebody

Comment: Ooo everbody deletes comments. Why ???

Comment: I may be blind (or lack of caffeine), but I don't see an implementation for insert.  Also, why did you re-implement `strtok_r`?  It is part of C (part of POSIX 1-2001) so I'd recommend using that version.

Comment: Also, don't implement `strtok_r` by calling `strtok`. It makes no sense. `strtok` is not thread-safe, hence `strtok_r` was written. You've now implemented a non-threadsafe version of `strtok_r`, which is useless; one might as well just use `strtok`.

Comment: But when I write strtok_r , there is an error. @abligh

Comment: I don't write insertion. because there is no mistake in that part. My problem is using strtok_r. @thurizas

Comment: @jasmine - suggest you find out why that is then.

Comment: But I don't find . I think everything is allright. @abligh

Comment: Do you know any source code or helping code for split with using strtok from a txt file ?@abligh

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17886258/971127

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a sample of how to do this.  I am using your lesson file (which I renamed to temp.txt) and I am also doing this on Linux using gcc version 4.8.2 running on Ubuntu.  I also removed `strtok_r` because `strtok_r` is a thread-safe version of `strtok` and because you are not using threads I see no reason to use a reenterant version.  Finally I added a bit, but just a bit, of error checking.  Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  FILE*  fp = NULL;
  int    ndx = 0;
  char   lines[100][100];

  if(NULL != (fp = fopen("./temp.txt", "r")))
  {
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
      fgets(lines[ndx++], sizeof(lines), fp);
    }

    for(ndx = 0; ndx < 3; ndx++)
    {
      char*      name;
      char*      list;

      name = strtok(lines[ndx], ":");
      list = strtok(NULL, ":");

      printf("Name: %s  List: %s", name, list);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Unable to open temp.txt, error is %d\n", errno);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Sample run on my computer:

```
******@ubuntu:~/junk$ gcc -ansi -Wall -pedantic array.c -o array
******@ubuntu:~/junk$ ./array
Name: George Adam              List: Math,Science,Germany
Name: Elizabeth McCurry        List: Music,Math,History
Name: Tom Hans                 List: Science,Music
******@ubuntu:~/junk$
```

Hopefully, this should be enough to get you started.  If not feel free to ask another question or modify this one.  I see you are using Windows, but the above code should be generic enough to compile there, just be advised that you may need to add an include file or two.